# receiving X509 client certificates in web requests

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httprequest, x509certificate

I am trying to send an X509Certificate from an Http Handler to a web service that will receive and read the certificate to authenticate the user.  I know the certificate is sending fine; I have a tester that lets me look at the `HttpWebRequest` before sending, and the `ClientCertificates` property shows that it has a certificate attached. (e.g. `request.ClientCertificates.Count = 1`).

However, on the other side on the web service, `HttpRequest.ClientCertificate` is consistently showing `NULL`.  I have looked at a number of Microsoft KB examples and all of them are using the same technique for inserting the certificate.  Other unrelated articles show that `HttpRequest.ClientCertificate` is the preferred way of reading it in.

So what am I doing wrong, and how can I determine on the server that a client certificate was sent?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps configuring your `HttpListener` with `clientcertnegotiation=enable` with [`netsh`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725882%28WS.10%29.aspx) would help (this makes the server negotiate the client-certificate during the initial handshake, as opposed to using re-negotiation).

It may also depend on whether you've initialised the certificate on the client side with its private key, see [Can't connect to HTTPS using X509 client certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901105/cant-connect-to-https-using-x509-client-certificate)