# HttpListenerRequest is not returning a client certificate

Tags: c#, ssl, .net-2.0

I'm using an `HttpListener` to create a very basic web server.  I've got it setup to use SSL using the httpcfg tool to bind to the appropriate port and certificate.  This seems to be working fine.  I'd now like to use client certificate authentication.  So I added a call to `GetClientCertificate` on the `HttpListenerRequest` object but it is always coming back with `null`.  My test client is very simple:

```
HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://127.0.0.1:8080/ssltest/");
webReq.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2("ssltest.pfx", "ssltest"));
webReq.GetResponse();
```

I noticed that the httpcfg tool has a flag that indicates if client certificates should be negotiated so I tried specifying that flag (`-f 2`) but I'm still not getting the client cert.  I also came across [this Microsoft support issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933907) which seems pretty relevant but I'm using the latest .NET 2.0 service pack and I've also tried the httpcfg flag both of which should avoid the issue.

I am assuming I am missing something obvious here.  Any ideas?

Edit: I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450911/receiving-x509-client-certificates-in-web-requests) which seems very relevant (maybe even a duplicate?).  Unfortunately there is no accepted answer for that question either.  The suggested answer makes a suggestion for something I already tried (httpcfg tool with the appropriate flag).

Comment: Are you sure that the cert is being properly loaded? I would write out some debug properties of the cert object to the console to be sure.

Comment: Fair enough.  Just tried this and the X509Certificate2 object is valid prior to my adding it to the ClientCertificates collection.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I would expect to see a CER file, not a PFX file there...the PFX file would contain the private key as well, which you shouldn't need for an SSL request. Still, I would expect this to work. Maybe try exporting just the public key for a CER file?

Comment: In a mutually authenticated SSL session both the client and the server need their own key pairs.  Each party authenticates the other using standard public key crypto procedures (asymmetric key validation, certificate path validation, etc).

Comment: Yes, but you don't SEND your private key. You only exchange your public keys. If I were signing the request, it would make sense that I needed the PFX.

Comment: Is ssltest.pfx the client cert ? Is it different from the server cert ?

Comment: @Yahia - yes, it is a self signed key pair that I created for the client and it is different from the server's cert (though that shouldn't really matter, right?).

Comment: self-signed certs fail on validation (as they should!) - if need be you can tweak the validation process (but NEVER use such relaxed validation in production!).

Comment: Right, this is obviously just for testing/development.  I'd be OK if the cert failed validation but the server isn't even getting the cert at all and therefore no validation is even taking place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895971/en-us the [`HttpWebRequest.ClientCertificates.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148415.aspx) performs validation already so the cert fails validation on the client-side and never gets sent.

**The above link contains code to relax the validation... NEVER use that in production!!!**

Comment: Wow, that was exactly it.  I probably should have known that since it works the same way for the server (the key pair has to be added to your store for it to work).  I also realized that I had added the cert to my personal store initially (windows wants to add it there automatically) but it needs to be in the trusted root store.  Thanks for your help.