# IT-Hit WebDav Server and client certificate?

Tags: authentication, ssl, webdav, ithit-webdav-server

Does anyone know if it the IT-Hit WebDav Server (http://www.webdavsystem.com/server) can accept and check client certificates? Perhaps it is something that IIS does for the product when deployed in an IIS?

Comment: And what did their support say?

Comment: Actually, they told me to post the question here...

Comment: Strange answer from their support, I must say. Indeed you can setup IIS for client-side authentication and this question is not directly related to their component but I thought they should know the answer, as this is a common usage scenario for the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT Hit WebDAV Server is based on IIS or HttpListener (two different implementations).

IIS supports client certificates, this means WebDAV Server based on IIS will work fine. All you need to do is setup your IIS.

As I see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153268/httplistenerrequest-is-not-returning-a-client-certificate) HttpListener supports client certificates too. If you are missing something to make it work (can not reach some property for example), please contact me.